# Special Series Summation

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the value of : $$1 + \frac{0.9}{11} +\frac{0.99}{11^2} +\frac{0.999}{11^3}+\cdots$$

1) $1089/990$

2) $1981/1090$

3) $989/990$

4) $1189/1090$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S=1+\dfrac{.9}{11}+\dfrac{.99}{11^2}+\dfrac{.999}{11^3}+.....$

Then $\dfrac{0.1S}{11}=\dfrac{.1}{11}+\dfrac{.09}{11^2}+\dfrac{.099}{11^3}+.....$

$S-\dfrac{0.1S}{11}=1-\dfrac{.1}{11}+0.9[\dfrac{1}{11}+\dfrac{1}{11^2}+.....]$

$\dfrac{10.9S}{11}=\dfrac{10.9}{11}+\dfrac{0.9}{10}$

Solving, you get $S=\dfrac{1189}{1090}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that:
$$1 + (0.9/11) + (0.99/11^2) + (0.999/11^3) ...=\\
1+\frac{1-0.1}{11}+\frac{1-0.01}{11^2}+\frac{1-0.001}{11^3}+\cdots=\\
\left(1+\frac1{11}+\frac1{11^2}+\cdots \right)-\left(\frac{0.1}{11}+\frac{0.01}{11^2}+\cdots \right)$$
Inside the brackets are the infinitely descending geometric progressions. Can you finish? The answer must be $\frac{1189}{1090}.$

Answer (score 0):

The answer should at least be bigger than one, so option three is definitely wrong.

Do you really have to proof your answer?
If not, you can just try by doing a couple of summations.
And then you will see it should be option 4.

$ 1189/1090 =  1.090826 $

$1 + (0.9/11) + (0.99/11^2) + (0.999/11^3)+(0.9999/11^4)+(0.99999/11^5)+(0.999999/11^6)+(0.9999999/11^7) = 1.090826 $

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I am not only trying to figure out the answer for only this question, I am trying to figure out the logic to solve these type of questions

Answer (score 0):

What you have to compute is the limit when $n \rightarrow +\infty$ of 
$$S_n = 1+ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^k}{11^k}$$

So you have
$$S_n = 1+ \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac{1}{11} \right)^k - \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac{1}{110} \right)^k = \frac{1}{11} \times \frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{11}\right)^{n}}{1-\frac{1}{11}} - \frac{1}{110} \times\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{110}\right)^{n}}{1-\frac{1}{110}}$$

This converges to
$$S = 1+ \frac{1}{11} \times \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{11}} - \frac{1}{110} \times \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{110}} = \frac{1189}{1090}$$